# Cannot Load data in CKEditor with MVC2 asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, ckeditor

After i finished all the set up. The only final step that i stumbled is that, i cannot load data from SQL to CKEditor.

- When i removed `<%: Model.Service.ShortDescription%>`, and add text `aaaaaa`. It loaded OK.
- When i change text `<%: "aaaaaa" %>`. It didn't load.

  ```
  <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="Description" BasePath="~/Content/ckeditor" runat="server" FilebrowserImageBrowseUrl= "/Content/ckfinder/ckfinder.html"                            FilebrowserImageUploadUrl= "/Content/ckfinder/core/connector/asp/connector.asp"                            FilebrowserBrowseUrl="/Content/ckfinder/ckfinder.html" FilebrowserUploadUrl="/Content/ckfinder/core/connector/asp/connector.asp">
     <%: Model.Service.ShortDescription %></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
  ```